# Output from a printf call is not geting displayed on screen

Tags: c, linux, string

I'm getting a string from the keyboard, in C and Linux (Ubuntu 14.04):

```
char string[STR];    
fgets(string, STR, stdin);
```

And I've noticed that `strlen()` is not working.

So, I've decided to do the following:

```
int i = 0;    
while (string[i] != '\0') {
        printf("\nchar: %c\n", string[i]);
        i++;
}
printf("\nFinished");
```

I type `"hello"` as input, and the output is the following:

```
char: h

char: e

char: l

char: l

char: o

char:
```

`"Finished"` is never printed.

I can't see which is the problem. I suspect it's because the input read from keyboard doesn't have `'\0'` terminated?

Yesterday I was working with Windows, and was working fine with strings.

**EDIT:** STR is defined as 128.

Comment: Is `STR` big enough that `'hello\0'` fits within `string[STR]`?

Comment: Try `'\n'` after "Finished".

Comment: What do you mean with "`strlen` is not working"? Does it return a value you don't expect? Does it crash? Does it make the program cycle infinitely? Be specific.

Comment: fgets should add the terminating char unless there is not enough space

Comment: Detail on @R_Kapp   
Is STR big enough that `"hello\n\0"` fits within `string[STR]`?

Comment: @terence hill  Expect `fgets()` to always add the null character unless 1) `NULL` is returned  2)  size < 1.

Comment: STR is 128 long. I've edited the OP.

Comment: Here is my wild guess: the first code fragment inside a function; you return `string` to `main`, at which point you print it in the `while` loop, right? Otherwise, your code simply works ([demo](http://ideone.com/v4faaH)).

Comment: if "does not store '\0' at the end" was true, the output would not stop at the expected 6 lines of output.  So `string[]` _does_ contain a null character.

Comment: That is not related to Linux.

Comment: @Olaf so explain me why does work in Windows.

Comment: @Julen: Read the C standard. This is plain C and the standard does not differentiate between Windows, Linux or TOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the code snippets you posted, there's no obvious problem. My guess is that this is part of a larger program and what you observe is due to a *output buffering*.
The standard output stream is typically line buffered and will be flushed periodically (as the buffer becomes full).

So adding `\n` at the end of printf might fix it if `stdout` is attached to a terminal device. If you are redirecting it to a file (`./a.out >output`) then this won't fix it either. So try calling [`fflush()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html):

```
fflush(stdout);
```

after the printf call.

I say "part of larger program" because at the end of normal process termination, all the buffered output will be flushed. So there wouldn't be any need for manual flushing. On abnormal process termination, the buffered output may be lost.

Another way is to disable the `stdout` buffering completely using [`sebtuf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html):

```
setbuf(stdout, 0);
```

Comment: Adding `\n` works. I'll keep in mind this, and the other solutions you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. `fgets()` stores a `'\0'` as the last byte written (may not be the last position in the array).

**You need to check the return value of `fgets()`** *and most functions with a prototype in `<stdio.h>`*.

```
char x[100]; // unitialized, x[99] may be anything
if (!fgets(x, sizeof x, stdin)) /* error; contents of x are not trustworthy */;
x[strlen(x)] == '\0'; // true, always true
                      // provided the previous statement did not generate an error
```

Answer (score 1):

1.If `STR`'s values is smaller than the input string's (length + **termination character: '\0'**), the last character of your input string isn't stored in `char string[STR]`;. The function `strlen()` uses `'\0'` to determine the end of the string, that is why without it, it *"doesn't work"* and your program runs in an infinite loop.

2.Buffering may be the other cause, as @l3x perfectly explains.